# unnecessary horizontal scroll xcode

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, xcode6

I have implemented a UIScrollView, which has a content view. Content view contains the UILables to display texts. Eventhough i have the necessary vertical scrollview for long paragrpahs, there is an unnecessary horizontal scrollview as well. [image: This is the unnecessary space due to horizontal scroll]

[image: This is what i wanted.]

Comment: second image is the way i want it to show when the app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, position the control view horizontally center in container. This should prevent the horizontal scroll.